# Mysql INNER JOIN and HAVING COUNT

Tags: mysql

Hey MYSQL question here:

I have 3 tables, lets call them items, article and order_point, that look something like this (in simplified form):

```
item = |item_id|article_id|,   
article = |article_id|article_info|,  
order_point=|op_id|article_id|op_amount|
```

The items-table contains the physical items that are in store (one row per physical item). The article-table contains info about each type of physical item, and the order_point (the amount) names how many of each article should be kept in store at all times.

Now what I'd like to do is get each article_id that has fewer items in store than the order_point_amount.

So what I want is something like this:

```
SELECT article_id 
FROM item INNER JOIN order_point 
ON (item.article_id = order_point.article_id GROUP BY item.article_id 
HAVING COUNT(item)<order_point.op_amount)
```

The above code is not valid though and it's the last minutes of the work day so let's see if someone solves it before I do tomorrow!

EDIT: The problem in the query like it is is that order_point.op_amount is not known in the having clause.

Comment: You did not `group by`

Comment: Same problem with the group by, you are not required to in MYSQL as far as I've read. Anyhow I will include it.

Comment: you should ask question using http://sqlfiddle.com/ with proper input and expected output.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I did not know about that site and will do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're joining on columns with no duplicates, which is a very common case:

An inner join of A and B gives the result of A intersect B, i.e. the inner part of a venn diagram intersection.

An outer join of A and B gives the results of A union B, i.e. the outer parts of a venn diagram union.

Examples

Suppose you have two Tables, with a single column each, and data as follows:

```
A    B
-    -
1    3
2    4
3    5
4    6
```

Note that (1,2) are unique to A, (3,4) are common, and (5,6) are unique to B.

Inner join

An inner join using either of the equivalent queries gives the intersection of the two tables, i.e. the two rows they have in common.

```
select * from a INNER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;
select a.*,b.*  from a,b where a.a = b.b;

a | b
--+--
3 | 3
4 | 4
```

Left outer join

A left outer join will give all rows in A, plus any common rows in B.

```
select * from a LEFT OUTER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;
select a.*,b.*  from a,b where a.a = b.b(+);

a |  b  
--+-----
1 | null
2 | null
3 |    3
4 |    4
```

Full outer join

A full outer join will give you the union of A and B, i.e. All the rows in A and all the rows in B. If something in A doesn't have a corresponding datum in B, then the B portion is null, and vice versa.

```
select * from a FULL OUTER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;

 a   |  b  
-----+-----
   1 | null
   2 | null
   3 |    3
   4 |    4
null |    6
null |    5
```

I hope this will solve your problem! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM order_point 
INNER JOIN (SELECT item.article_id, COUNT(*) AS in_store
            FROM item INNER JOIN order_point 
            ON item.article_id = order_point.article_id
            GROUP BY item.article_id) AS TEMP
ON order_point.article_id = TEMP.article_id
WHERE TEMP.in_store<order_point.amount
GROUP BY order_point.article_id
```

This gives me the rows with fewer items **in store** than the requested **amount** , which is what I was after.